# Vendor Bill vs Vendor Credit / Ipp C#

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Is there a way using the IPP (in c#) to differentiate between a Bill and a Vendor Credit?  right now when I iterate through all the lines on a Bill Payment (A Check in this case) to show what bills are being paid Vendor Credits show up but they do not look any different from a bill (Amounts are positive, there is no Bill type etc).

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.BillPaymentQuery qbBillPaymentQuery = new BillPaymentQuery();
        qbBillPaymentQuery.DocNumber = "143766";
        List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.BillPayment> qboBP = qbBillPaymentQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.BillPayment>(context).ToList<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.BillPayment>();

        foreach (BillPayment b in qboBP)
        {
            Response.Write("Bill Payment Amount: " + b.Header.TotalAmt + "<BR>");

            foreach (BillPaymentLine x in b.Line)
            {
                Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.BillQuery qbBillQuery = new BillQuery();
                qbBillQuery.ResultsPerPage = 1;
                //qbBillQuery.PageNumber = 1;

                qbBillQuery.TxnId = x.TxnId;
                //qbBillQuery.SpecifyOperatorOption(FilterProperty.DocNumber, FilterOperatorType.EQUALS);


                 DataServices dataServices = new DataServices(context);
                 Bill b2 = new Bill();
                 b2.Id = x.TxnId;
                 Bill b3 = dataServices.FindById(b2);

                 Response.Write(b3.Header.DocNumber + " - " + x.Amount + "<BR>");




            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In QBO, **VendorCredit** is not fully supported for production use. It is available as part of a beta release.
Ref Doc - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/0500_supported_entities_and_operations

Answer (score 0):

You are right. I was able to replicate your issue. The vendor credit objects are also retrieved as bill objects, which should not be happening.

See sample xml, the first one is a bill, last 3 lines are credit memo.
There is really no differentiation between them. Also, the vendor credit amounts are incorrect for me
[image: Billpayement response xml]

[image: Company file Bill payment]

However, this is currently in beta stage for Vendor credits and cannot report this issue until they are production.